# what causes an NSTimer to run code slower than its supposed to

Tags: ios, performance, nstimer, behavior

i have an application where i use the NSTimer class to run code at a speed of 0.01, as the code shows

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector (method here) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

method that runs every 0.01 seconds:

```
UIImageView.center = CGPointMake(UIImageView.center.x , UIImageView.center.y + 2)
```

however this runs a bit laggy because the code is not running fast enough to make it look smooth, so i decided to run the code  faster :

```
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector (method here) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

method :

```
UIImageView.center = CGPointMake(UIImageView.center.x , UIImageView.center.y + 0.2)
```

this made me game look a lot smoother but, there are sometimes where the game lags for a second 
, and the UIImageView that is supposed to fall down at the specific speed fall down slower than it should be.

i think that since this code runs extremely fast it is causing it to lag, also i think that 
the RAM has to do with it since if there is free RAM it doesn't do that.

so my questions are:

-is there a way to fix it from lagging

-what causes it to lag.

Comment: Add the timer to main runloop and try

Comment: *Don't use `NSTimer` for animations!*

Comment: where is the main runloop, im still a beginner ,or actullay what is a main runloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead, it is better to use animations, an NSTimer will keep your main thread busy.

```
- (void)move{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        UIImageView.center = CGPointMake(UIImageView.center.x , UIImageView.center.y + 200);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self move];
    }];
}
```

Comment: `0.01` is a pretty short animation. It's actually shorter than a single frame (1/60 ≈ 0.01666666666666667...)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Yeah I just took the values from the OP. We could probably multiply by 100 or more, it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: I thank you for your help ,but I have tried your code out in my application , and it also looks laggy , I tried to play with the duration of the animation but it still laggy , it more laggy than the NSTimer I used , I think that it takes time to run the code again which is making it laggy

Comment: Is it laggy with a 1 second animation ? For me it's just smooth, and i've never experienced lag with animateWithDuration. What's the weight of your image ?

Comment: Yes it's laggy with an 1 second duration , this one second moves my image 2 units every time (tested on iPhone 5s) it moves 2 units then stops , then moves 2 units agian and stops, so on , for my image it is a plain green image I downloaded from the internet

Comment: I've edited my answer so that the animation is linear. Why do you need to move only 2 units each time ?

Comment: Thanks for your help , it works perfectly now , I just needed to add the linear option , and adjusted the duration , I also moved 200  units each time now.

Answer (score 2):

Using NSTimer for an animation is pretty bad to begin with.

Take a look at [UIView animateWithDuration:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)

You can then move your image in the animation block, smooth and without CPU or RAM problems.

Comment: Thanks , I tried the animation code , and it still looks laggy

Answer (score -1):

1. Looks like you have memory leak so first run profiler to search for memory leaks
2. Do not assume that each call of timer method will happen exactly on desired time. Measure time elapsed since last run for example using `NSDate` and `timeIntervaleSinceXXX` and use this value to update simulation or whatever you do.